# How to refresh XML data that is bound to a list in Flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, data-binding, refresh, mxml

### I am writing an app for the Blackberry Playbook using Flash Builder 4.6 and flex. I have run into an issue which I am hoping someone may be able to assist me with. It is as follows:

First off, I am making an app that allows a user to browse through various reddit feeds. I am making use of the reddit API, in which you are able to use either JSON or XML formatted data. I am using XML. Within Adobe Flash Builder I have run the 'Data/Services' wizard to connect to the data source which pulls in the latest 25 or so entries on Reddit. Then I bound that data to a spark List component which is housed in the view, 'redditFeed'. You will notice that it uses AsyncListView. This is the code:

**redditFeed.mxml**

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

public function myList_creationCompleteHandler():void
            {   

                getRedditFeedResult.token = redditFeedGrabber.getRedditFeed("");                    
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
        <s:CallResponder id="getRedditFeedResult"/>
        <redditfeedgrabber:RedditFeedGrabber id="redditFeedGrabber"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="redditFeedJSONResult"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

     <s:List id="feedList" width="100%" height="100%" change="myList_changeHandler(event)"
                contentBackgroundColor="#deefff" 
                creationComplete="myList_creationCompleteHandler()">
        <s:AsyncListView id="asyncList" list="{getRedditFeedResult.lastResult}"/>
            <s:itemRenderer>
                <fx:Component>
                    <s:IconItemRenderer iconField="thumbnail" 
                                        iconWidth="64" iconHeight="64"
                                        labelField="title" fontSize="20"
                                        messageField="pubDate"
                                        verticalAlign="top"
                                        iconPlaceholder="{assets.LoadingIcon}">
                        <fx:Script>
                            <![CDATA[
                                import assets.LoadingIcon;
                            ]]>
                        </fx:Script>
                    </s:IconItemRenderer>
                </fx:Component>
            </s:itemRenderer>



        </s:List>
```

Now for my problem; I have a refresh button named 'refreshButton'. I would like for the data in the spark List above to be refreshed when a user clicks this button. I have searched far and wide for a solution, to no avail. 
So, how am I able to reload the xml data that is bound to the list, and then have the list show this new data? 
I appreciate any help you can provide. Please let me know if there is anything more I can provide to help you in assisting me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should have to do is make the same call that's made in the creation complete handler in your button click handler. Setting the token and making the call again should force a refresh when the ASyncToken gets a result.

Comment: Ah, but must i first clear out the list or the data somehow? cause it doesnt seem to want to update.

Comment: I believe lastResult is bindable and should fire a property change event triggering the value to be reassigned put a breakpoint on the mxml binding line and run in debug mode you should see it hit the point after you click your button.

Comment: When I call the function from inside of the mxml view that contains the function, it works. Otherwise, if I call it from a different mxml view, it doesnt. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code for how you're making the call from the other MXML file?  I'm not sure why this would affect anything so long as you're assigning an id to the mxml component and calling through the instance it's showing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9222639/1176170   I just posted a new question for this issue, as it delves beyond what is discussed here. Maybe you could take a look? Thanks again!