# How do I use a SplitViewNavigator component to show Master/Detail navigation in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, view, mxml

### I am having an issue with using the SplitViewNavigator component in flex 4.6 using Adobe Flash Builder.

[UPDATED]* * *

I am building a reddit app for the blackberry playbook tablet, and am making use of reddit's API. I have three mxml views: RedditReaderHomeView.mxml, redditFeed.mxml, and subredditList.mxml. In RedditReaderHomeView.mxml I have a splitViewNavigator. In left side of my SplitViewNavigator resides subredditList.mxml, and on the right side resides redditFeed.mxml. On initialization, redditFeed.mxml pulls in XML data to populate its list with reddit entries, and subredditList.mxml pulls in XML data which populates its list with subreddits(categories) to display. When a user clicks on of the subreddit entries on the left, the redditFeed.mxml on the right should update so that the data it pulls are entries from the subreddit category that was selected on the left. In other words, classic master/detail navigation. Category on the left, which opens entries of that category on the right.

Well, I have a function that passes the url of the selected subreddit over to redditFeed.mxml.

**subredditList.mxml** - here a subreddit is selected and its url is sent over to a function in redditFeed.mxml

```
public function list_clickHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
                var RSSItem:Object = redditList.dataProvider.getItemAt(event.newIndex);
                var thisItem:Item = RSSItem as Item;
                rlink = thisItem.link;
                var moddedLink:String = rlink.slice(1, int.MAX_VALUE)
                var pushSub:redditFeed = new redditFeed();
                pushSub.myList_creationCompleteHandler(moddedLink);
            }
```

**redditFeed.mxml** - the url is used to grab data from that particular subreddit...

```
public function myList_creationCompleteHandler(url:String):void
            { 
                getRedditFeedResult.token = redditFeedGrabber.getRedditFeed(url);
            }
```

... though this data never seems to be displayed in the spark List component, even though I can see the call being made through the Network Monitor.
I've spent hours and hours trying to solve this. And I belive it has something to do with views being 'active' vs. 'deactivated', as when i tried placing this same call from within redditFeed.mxml, the call went through and the data in the list updated. I thought perhaps this was because the action was being performed within the same view that contains the list where the data is displayed. So it would be 'active' in this instance as the action is being performed in that view.

I appreciate any help anyone can offer. Also, dont hesitate to request clarification/more details from me. I reeeallly want to solve this. 
Thanks!

**RedditReaderHomeView.mxml** - Here's the code you requested. Lemme know if you need more/something else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        actionBarVisible="false" tabBarVisible="true" title="Reddit Reader by Domisy" creationPolicy="all"
        actionBarVisible.landscape="true">



    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.adobe.fiber.core.model_public;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import views.redditFeed;

            public var defUrl:String = new String("");


            public function refreshRSS(event:Event):void
            {
                          //***UPDATED CODE****
                          var refreshFunction:Object = redditFeedNav.getElementAt(0);
                  refreshFunction.refreshList();


                          //var refreshFunction:redditFeed = new redditFeed();
            //refreshFunction.refreshList();                
            }
        ]]>

    </fx:Script>


    <fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>



    <s:states>
        <s:State name="portrait"/>
        <s:State name="landscape"/>
    </s:states>




    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button includeIn="landscape" click="navigator.pushView(profileView)"
                  icon="@Embed('assets/images/profileIcon.png')"/>
    </s:actionContent>




    <s:SplitViewNavigator width="100%" height="100%" id="splitViewNavigator" autoHideFirstViewNavigator="true">
        <s:ViewNavigator id="redditListNav" firstView="views.subredditList" width="300" height="100%"/>
        <s:ViewNavigator id="redditFeedNav" firstView="views.redditFeed" width="100%" height="100%">



            <s:actionContent.landscape>
                <s:Button id="refreshButtonlLandscape" icon="@Embed('assets/refresh160.png')" click="refreshRSS(event)" />
            </s:actionContent.landscape>

            <s:actionContent.portrait>
                <s:Button id="refreshButton" icon="@Embed('assets/refresh160.png')" click="refreshRSS(event)" />
                <s:Button id="navigatorButton" label="Search" click="splitViewNavigator.showFirstViewNavigatorInPopUp(navigatorButton)" />
            </s:actionContent.portrait>
        </s:ViewNavigator>
    </s:SplitViewNavigator>


</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I see what the problem is I think.  You're creating a new instance of the redditFeed object instead of using the one instantiated in MXML.  In your RedditReaderHomeView.mxml give the declaration of redditFeed an id, then in the function above use it like:

```
private var redditFeedId:RedditFeed; //Passed in from RedditReaderHome, bound to the id of the actual one in there
public function list_clickHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
     var RSSItem:Object = redditList.dataProvider.getItemAt(event.newIndex);
     var thisItem:Item = RSSItem as Item;
     rlink = thisItem.link;
     var moddedLink:String = rlink.slice(1, int.MAX_VALUE)
     redditFeedId.myList_creationCompleteHandler(moddedLink);
 }
```

Paste in RedditReaderHome if you end up needing any help on that.

Thanks for following up [ADDED]

```
        public function refreshRSS(event : Event) : void
        {
            trace(redditFeedNav.getElementAt(0));
            redditFeedNav.getElementAt(0).refreshList(); 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't wait to try this out when I get home. And yes if you could show me how to give the declaration of redditFeed an id, that would be great.  Ill post some code when I get home.

Comment: Alright, I pasted in the code for RedditReaderHomeView. Now how do I declare redditFeed, specifically without throwing a Flex error #1009 (cannot access a property or method of a null object reference)? Thanks!

Comment: hey yeah still need to work out the details a bit due to the view creation/destruction explained here: http://corlan.org/2011/01/12/understanding-flex-mobile-views-and-viewnavigator/

Comment: so based off the info from the link above, It seems somehow I have to prevent the view from being destroyed, or somehow keep it active so that I can access it's components. In all three mxml files i have set the 'destructionPolicy="never"' so I already tried that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi sorry this took me so long to get back to, grabbing the 4.6 SDK right now to test out locally, think you may need to use redditFeedNav.navigatorContent, but downloading then I'll debug and let you know what I'm seeing.

Comment: @TheoMavrakis added a bit to the answer above for the issue regarding getting a handle on the actual view you want to call the refresh method on, seems to work fine locally, let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: awesome i cant thank you enough for all your help! imma try it as soon as i get home and ill let you know. looks promising

Comment: great, hope it works out, let me know either way, always good to have these things in the tool box

Comment: Hmmmm, so I came up with something based on your addition to your answer. it can be seen above under refreshList() function in 'RedditReaderHomeView.mxml' code above.    With that in mind, the original question wasnt based off this function, but rather how to update the reddditFeed respectively when a user clicks a subreddit. So how am I able to do this with the same idea in mind?

Comment: Sorry I think I got lost on this one I'll take a look tomorrow.  Feel free to contact me on gmail/chat same as my username here but with a dot in the middle.  It might be more conducive to have a dialogue that way then bring the solution here.  Thanks have a good night... morning... whatever it is where you are when you get this.